# Using a generic C# interface as a class property

Tags: c#

I have an interface

```
public interface ICallback<T> 
{
    void OnSuccess (T data);
    void OnFailure (Exception exception);
}
```

and a class

```
public class ToDoTask 
{
    private int someInt;

    public string StringProperty {get; set;}

    public ICallback Callback {get; private set;}
}
```

This doesn't compile because it wants me to specialize the `Callback` property. I don't want to specialize the property because I don't know the type. The type is determined at runtime through reflection.

Here's a small explanation of what happens:

1. A proxy class is generated (via `CreateInterfaceProxyWithoutTarget<C>` of *Castle DynamicProxy*) at runtime to implement a given interface (Let's call this `IModel`)
2. A call is made to a method of this proxy class (remember, there's no target so there's no code that executes here aside from what my interceptor does)
3. The method calls are intercepted by a main class that decides what needs to be done based on the attributes on the method and it's parameters (as defined in `IModel`)
4. At this point, ***if*** the last parameter of the intercepted method is an `ICallback<T>`, it gets assigned to the `Callback` property, otherwise it's `null`.
5. If the callback is *not* null, the operation result is parsed and the appropriate callback method is called.

This is what the Interceptor class looks like:

```
public class Intercepteur : IInterceptor{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation) {
        ToDoTask task = Study(invocation);

        /* 
           nothing past this point is actually written, 
           so there may be typos or compile errors below
        */

        try 
        {
            var result = Perform(task);

            if (null != task.Callback)
               task.Callback.OnSuccess (MagicalTransformation (result, typeof (T)));
        } catch (Exception e) 
        {
            if (null != task.Callback)
                task.Callback.OnFailure (e);
        }
    }
}
```

Is it safe to declare the callback as `ICallback<object>` and cast & return at runtime?

If any of the above sounds stupid, its because I don't have much experience with reflection in C# and I'm diving deep into c# after about 4 years of not touching it. Be nice!

Comment: what if the `Callback` property is not *auto generate* and `Set` this with a `ServisFactory`?

Answer (score 3):

You need to define what `T` is, or use another option.

The three simplest ways to fix this would be:

**Have `T` defined by `ToDoTask<T>`**

```
public interface ICallback<T> {
    void OnSuccess (T data);
    void OnFailure (Exception exception);
}

public class ToDoTask<T> {
    private int someInt;

    public string StringProperty {get; set;}

    public ICallback<T> Callback {get; private set;}
}
```

**Define the `OnSuccess` method as generic, rather than the interface**

```
public interface ICallback
{
    void OnSuccess<T>(T data);
    void OnFailure(Exception exception);
}

public class ToDoTask<T>
{
    private int someInt;

    public string StringProperty { get; set; }

    public ICallback Callback { get; private set; }
}
```

**Use `object` instead of `T`**

```
public interface ICallback {
    void OnSuccess (object data);
    void OnFailure (Exception exception);
}

public class ToDoTask {
    private int someInt;

    public string StringProperty {get; set;}

    public ICallback Callback {get; private set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ICallBack` does not exist, it must be `ICallBack<T>` so you need to provide a type - or make `ToDoTask` generic and pass the type to `ICallBack`.

like so:

```
class ToDoTask<T>{
   ...
   ICallBack<T> CallBack {get;set;}
}
```

And then pass in the type after reflection or whatever.

A less safer alternative is to use `dynamic`. Here is a sample program that is trying to do something similar to what you're trying

```
class Program
{
    interface ICallBack<T>
    {
        void SetObject(T obj);
    }

    class CallBackUser<T>
    {
        public dynamic CB { get; set; }
    }

    class CB<T> : ICallBack<T>
    {
        public void SetObject(T obj)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Works");
        }
    }

    static Type GetMyTypeThroughReflection()
    {
        return typeof (int);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Type t = GetMyTypeThroughReflection();
        Type genericClass = typeof(CallBackUser<>);
        Type constructedClass = genericClass.MakeGenericType(t);

        dynamic created = Activator.CreateInstance(constructedClass);
        created.CB = new CB<int>();
        created.CB.SetObject(0);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, since generics is a `compile time` feature, you will need to specify the time at compile time.

When you use reflection(runtime), you would prefer working with base types and use `polymorphism` to accomplish things like this.

I didn't understand by 100% what you wanted to do but you can:

1.Use an `ICallback<DeriveType>` and work with `polymorphism` or `object` in the worst case(be carefull to **avoid** boxing\unboxing of value types).
2.Create an non generic interface that will look something like this:

```
public interface ICallback {
    void OnSuccess (DeriveType data);
    void OnFailure (Exception exception);
}
```